# How do I write this coffee script in javascript or jquery?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm using this coffeescript to javascript converter http://coffeescript.org/ to work through a coffeescript tutorial (to improve both my coffeescript and jquery). However, when I try to do it with the following coffeescript, which was originally found in an jst.eco template file, it doesn't work, even if I remove the `<% %>` Similarily, I tried to run the code on a live site and find out the compiled javascript using Firebug but the only file it showed me was the jquery file.

```
<% for entry in @entries.models: %>
  <li><%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% end %>
```

How would you write this in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not just Coffeescript, that is an eco template, i.e. an HTML template with embedded coffeescript code, similar to, say, JSP or PHP. It does something similar to

```
var entry, x, _i, _len, _ref;

x = [];

_ref = this.entries.models;
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  entry = _ref[_i];
  x.push('<li>');
  x.push(entry.get('name'));
  x.push('</li>');
}

return x;
```

You may want to look at using an equivalent templating engine. jQuery itself apparently [has one in beta-testing](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/).

Comment: Thanks, I put each of those lines in side <% %> in a jst.ejs file and it didn't work. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or, less likely, your code isn't correct

Comment: side note: don't use jquery templates. they are not supported anymore, while the team does a ground-up re-write in the jQueryUI project. http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you should be able to write:

```js
<% $.each(this.entries.models, function (key, entry) { %>
  <li><%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% }) %>
```

in vanilla Javascript

```js
<% this.entries.models.forEach(function (entry) { %>
  <li><%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% }) %>
```

If `this.entries.models` is a Backbone Collection the forEach method is provided by underscore.

Comment: thanks, but what type of file/file extension should this code go into if it's in the templates folder in Backbone? It can't go into an eco file because function is a reserved word.

Comment: EJS https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs - a template engine like eco but for vanilla javascript